# How to call an overridden function in a method in the Parent class

Tags: php

I have an abstract class which defines three methods: `act`, `calculateStat` and `calculateRelationship`. Within the `act` method, I make calls to both `calculateStat` and `calculateRelationship`.

Ideally, I would like to be able to, within the child class, override these methods, and have them be called by the `act` method within the parent's `act` method, but the implementation I have tried to do this doesn't appear to work; it will only use the parent's `calculateStat` and `calculateRelationship` methods.

```php
abstract class Action {

    protected $name = 'Generic';
    protected $acts_on = Person::STAT_GENERIC;
    protected $action_points = 1;

    public function act($performer, $performee) {
        // Get Perfomer and Performee stats
        $performer_stat = $performer->getStat($this->acts_on);
        $performee_stat = $performee->getStat($this->acts_on);

        // Calculate values
        $new_stat = $this->calculateStat($performer_stat, $performee_stat);

        // Apply values
        $performee->setStat($this->acts_on, $new_stat);

        $stat_diff = $new_stat - $performee_stat;
        $relationship = $performee->getRelationship($performer->getID());

        $new_relationship = $this->calculateRelationship($relationship, $stat_diff);

        $performee->setRelationship($performer->getID(), $new_relationship);

        // Output
        Output::getInstance()->addOutput($performer->getName() . ' performed ' . $this->name . ' on ' . $performee->getName() . ' making their stat change from ' . $performee_stat . ' to ' . $new_stat);
        Output::getInstance()->addOutput($performee->getName() . '\'s relationship with ' . $performer->getName() . ' changed from ' . $relationship . ' to ' . $new_relationship);

    }

    private function calculateStat($performer_stat, $performee_stat) {
        $performer_multiplier = 2 * $performer_stat / Person::STAT_MAX;
        $new_stat = $performee_stat + ($this->action_points * $performer_multiplier);

        if ($new_stat > Person::STAT_MAX) {
            $new_stat = Person::STAT_MAX;
        }

        return $new_stat;
    }

    private function calculateRelationship($relationship, $stat_diff) {
        if ($stat_diff < 0) {
            $relationship_multiplier = -1;
        } else {
            $relationship_multiplier = 1;
        }

        $new_relationship = $relationship_multiplier * ($relationship + ($stat_diff / 2));

        return $new_relationship;
    }
}
```

Within a child class, it doesn't call the overridden method:

```php
class ActionClub extends Action {

    protected $name = 'Club';
    protected $acts_on = Person::STAT_GENERIC;
    protected $action_points = -20;


    private function calculateStat($performer_stat, $performee_stat) {
        return 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of that `private` mean? You probably want use `protected` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by updating the scope of the methods from `private` to `protected`.